# Duplicate records referenced in Many-To-Many relationships

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, duplicates

I'm currently coding a stored procedure which creates an exact copy of an existing object.
The object uses multiple tables, where 2 of those tables use a many-to-many relationship:

Here is the schema used:

```
---------------------------------------
          tbl_AssociationA
---------------------------------------
ID  |  ObjectID |    Description
---------------------------------------
1   |  12       |    'Some description'
2   |  12       |    'Some text here'
3   |  13       |    'Some words here'
               ...
---------------------------------------


---------------------------------------
          tbl_AssociationB
---------------------------------------
ID  |  ObjectID |    LabelText
---------------------------------------
1   |  12       |    'Foo'
2   |  12       |    'Foo foo'
3   |  13       |    'Some words...'
4   |  13       |    'Some other Foos'
5   |  14       |    'Some foos here'
6   |  12       |    'Some other words'
               ...
---------------------------------------


-------------------------
    tbl_RelationAB
-------------------------
ID_A      |  ID_B
-------------------------
1         |  1     
2         |  1    
2         |  2     
2         |  6     
3         |  4      
3         |  3      
          ...
------------------------
```

Now, let's say I want to create a copy of `Object 12` (Let's call it `Object X`). I want to copy records from `tbl_AssociationA` and `tbl_AssociationB`, since I don't want further modifications on `Object X` to modify `Object 12`.

So, to create new records in `tbl_AssociationA` and `tbl_AssociationB`, I would use this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_AssociationA
SELECT @NewId,Description FROM tbl_AssociationA WHERE ObjectID=@NewId;

INSERT INTO tbl_AssociationB
SELECT @NewId,LabelText FROM tbl_AssociationB WHERE ObjectID=@NewId;
```

How can I insert into `tbl_RelationAB` using those newly created records. Note that column `ID` in `tbl_AssociationA` and `tbl_AssociationB` is `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Use scope_identity to retrieve the Iden  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the deal was:

> I want to copy Object X to Object Z.
>   Object X is referenced in `tbl_AssociationA` and `tblAssociationB` with foreign key `ObjectID`.
>   A 3rd table, `tbl_RelationAB`, specifies the many-to-many mapping between `tbl_AssociationA.ID` and `tbl_AssociationB.ID`.

In this solution, Object X is referenced with `@originalObjectID` and Object Z with `@copiedObjectID`. The 2 temporary tables `@TempA` and `@TempB` are used to keep a mapping between the old and the new auto-generated `ID` columns of `tbl_AssociationA` and `tbl_AssociationB`.

```
DECLARE @TempA AS TABLE (newID INT, oldID INT);
DECLARE @TempB AS TABLE (newID INT, oldID INT);

MERGE tbl_AssociationA AS tbl_a
USING (
    SELECT ID, ObjectID, Description
    FROM tbl_AssociationA WHERE ObjectID=@originalObjectID
) as old_tbl_a
ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ObjectID,Description) VALUES (@copiedObjectID,Description)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID,old_tbl_a.ID INTO @TempA;

MERGE tbl_AssociationB AS tbl_b
USING (
    SELECT ID, ObjectID, LabelText
    FROM tbl_AssociationB WHERE ObjectID=@originalObjectID
) as old_tbl_b
ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (ObjectID,LabelText) VALUES (@copiedObjectID,LabelText)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ID,old_tbl_b.ID INTO @TempB;

INSERT INTO tbl_RelationAB
SELECT a.newID,b.newID
FROM tbl_RelationAB tbl_ab
INNER JOIN @TempA a ON tbl_ab.ID_A = a.oldID
INNER JOIN @TempB b ON tbl_ab.ID_B = b.oldID;
```

So table `tbl_RelationAB` then also gets copied the relation between the new auto-generated `tbl_AssociationA.ID` and `tbl_AssociationB.ID`. Hope this can help someone in the future!

Answer (score 2):

I am reusing the same table and no insert.
But this shows how to retrieve the two iden and use them in a statement.

```
  set nocount on;
  declare @idenA SmallInt, @idenB SmallInt; 
  insert into Table_1(value) values('a');
  set @idenA = scope_identity();
  insert into Table_1(value) values('b');
  set @idenB = scope_identity();
  print @idenA;
  print @idenB;

  insert into Table_1 (value)
  OUTPUT inserted.* 
  select top 2 value from Table_1
```

But I understand that is not a full answer to your question.
I think you are going to need to output to a temp table.
Once you get a better answer I will delete this one.

Comment: @NewID is the newly generated ObjectID, but the insert would generate multiple identity for tables `tbl_AssociationA` and  `tbl_AssociationB`. These multiple auto-generated IDs, I don't know how to retrieve them all...

Comment: OUTPUT seems to be what I need, but How could I OUTPUT into a temporary table, the newly generated ID with the associated original ID?

Comment: Hey Blam, I managed to do it by myself! Maybe you could check if it could be done in a simpler way, but I doubt. Still, +1 for the `OUTPUT` hint! Thank you